# Unable to maximize running Terminal in Ubuntu 16.04 (VM Ware player)

Tags: 16.04, gnome-terminal, vmware

I am working with a Terminal, where build is under process.
In parallel, there were another terminal opened.

When I click on Terminal slide bar i can see names/paths of both terminals.
I closed unwanted terminal to see build running Terminal.

But I can't maximize and see anything. What could be the problem?
How to revert it back?

**NOTE** : Running Ubuntu 16.04 in VM Ware player.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in Ubuntu you can maximize any window by selecting the window and pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>↑</kbd> buttons. And minimize windows by selecting the window and pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>↓</kbd> buttons